# Quasi-coherent sheaves on a complex manifold form an abelian category?

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

Quasi-coherent modules on a ringed space is defined in [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BE).  Is there a complex manifold $X$ such that the category of quasi-coherent $O_X$-modules   is not an abelian subcategory of the category of all $O_X$-modules?

Comment: Dear @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, do you have any evidence? I agree that "coherent" sheaves are useful in the study of complex manifolds.

Comment: Do you think cohomology is important? These are usually defined using injective resolutions and in general, injective modules are only quasi-coherent.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, thank you for your comment. On a complex manifold $X$, the cohomology of coherent modules is defined as Cech cohomolgy relative to a Stein covering, in p.35 of "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" by Grauert and Remmert. For an $O_X$-modules, we can define its cohomology using injective objects of $\mathrm{Mod}(O_X)$, the category of ALL $O_X$-modules. I don't know whether the category $\mathrm{Qch}(X)$ is  abelian, let alone how to define injective objects in $\mathrm{Qch}(X)$.